# Can I refer to my own blog in a Stack Overflow answer?

Tags: discussion

I am currently building a blog in my area of expertise with a few colleagues. We hope to address answers to lots of frequently asked questions in this field. Is it appropriate/allowed to refer to our blog in a Stack Overflow answer?

I’d obviously port the relevant information across so users can see the base information to answer their question, but for deeper learning link to my blog.

It feels shamefully like self promotion, and I wanted to check before stepping out of line.