# Is it acceptable to cite one's own article?

Tags: discussion, citation

I wonder if it is acceptable to cite to one's own academic paper or blog article to answer someone else's question in Stack Exchange sites.

Let's suppose that the answer or the cited contents is appropriate answer to the question and there is no financial benefit from the response...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)

Comment: @cigien I appreciate your suggestion but the link does not answer my question. I have a concern in a very special situation when that 'external resource' is of one's own writing.

Comment: That's covered in the FAQ. There are questions specific to linking to your own content e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313642 if you want, but they all link to the FAQ.

Comment: A Q&A that recognizes and supports people correctly citing external sources: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260365/282094 - not too much of a stretch to say it answers this question, though the question there is entirely different.

Answer (score 4):

Well - If its as part of a broader answer, and your main goal here isn't 'just' to cite those papers? Sure, but the source you cite will be judged by its own merits. I think the [self promotion rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)  should be a useful starting point here.

If its relevant, and there's *clear* self attribution, there should be no issue.